# Как с помощью Linq узнать сколько вхождений i-ого элемента в последовательность?

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var var1 = arr.Count(i => i);
            

        }
```

Ошибка: Нельзя неявно преобразовать тип int в bool.
Метод же должен вернуть кол-во(число).
У меня неправильно написан делегат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цикл не нужен.

```
int i = 3;
int count = arr.Count(x => x == arr[i]);
```

Посчитает сколько раз встречается 3 элемент в массиве.

Причина вашей ошибки в том, что метод `Count` принимает предикат (условие, возвращающее да или нет), `i => i` в свою очередь означает для каждого элемента выбрать его же, возвращаемый тип выходит не `bool`, а `int`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.